# I have create admin grid in magento 1.9 .It was not working getCollection error how to solve please help me

Tags: magento-1.9, database, product-attribute, new-products, learn-magento

my **config.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
  <modules>
    <Epage_Developer>
      <version>1.6.0</version>
    </Epage_Developer>
  </modules>
  <frontend>
    <routers>
      <developer>
        <use>standard</use>
        <args>
          <module>Epage_Developer</module>
          <frontName>developer</frontName>
        </args>
      </developer>
    </routers>
    <layout>
      <updates>
        <developer>
          <file>developer.xml</file>
        </developer>
      </updates>
    </layout>
  </frontend>
  <admin> 
    <routers>
      <developer>
        <use>admin</use>
        <args>
          <module>Epage_Developer</module>
          <frontName>admin_developer</frontName>
        </args>
      </developer>
      <adminhtml>
        <args>
          <modules>
            <developer before="Mage_Adminhtml">Epage_Developer_Adminhtml</developer>
          </modules>
        </args>
      </adminhtml>
    </routers>
  </admin>
  <global>
    <models>
      <developer>
        <class>Epage_Developer_Model</class>
        <resourceModel>developer_resource</resourceModel>
      </developer>
      <developer_resource>
        <class>Epage_Developer_Model_Resource</class>
        <entities>
          <developer>
            <table>developer</table>
          </developer>
        </entities>
      </developer_resource>
    </models>
    <resources>
      <developer_setup>
        <setup>
          <module>Epage_Developer</module>
        </setup>
        <connection>
          <use>core_setup</use>
        </connection>
      </developer_setup>
      <developer_write>
        <connection>
          <use>core_write</use>
        </connection>
      </developer_write>
      <developer_read>
        <connection>
          <use>core_read</use>
        </connection>
      </developer_read>
    </resources> 
    <blocks>
      <developer>
        <class>Epage_Developer_Block</class>
      </developer>
    </blocks>
    <helpers>
      <developer>
        <class>Epage_Developer_Helper</class>
      </developer>
    </helpers>
  </global>
  <adminhtml>
    <menu>
      <developer module="developer">
        <title>developer</title>
        <sort_order>100</sort_order>
        <children>
          <developer module="developer">
            <title>Manage Developer</title>
            <sort_order>0</sort_order>
            <action>admin_developer/adminhtml_developer</action>
          </developer>
        </children>
      </developer>
    </menu>
    <acl>
      <resources>
        <all>
          <title>Alloe Everything</title> 
        </all>
        <admin>
          <children>
            <developer translate="title" module="developer">
              <title>developer</title>
              <sort_order>1000</sort_order>
              <children>
                <developer translate="title">
                  <title>Manage Developer</title>
                  <sort_order>0</sort_order>
                </developer>
              </children>
            </developer>
          </children>
        </admin>
      </resources>
    </acl>
    <layout>
      <updates>
        <developer>
          <file>developer.xml</file>
        </developer>
      </updates>
    </layout>
  </adminhtml>
</config>
```

> Local/Epage/Developer/Model/Developer.php

```
class Epage_Developer_Model_Developer extends Mage_Core_Model_Abstract {

  protected function _construct() { 
    parent::_construct ();
    $this->_init('developer/developer');
  }

  public function savedeveloper($developer){
    $enquireCollection = Mage::getModel('developer/developer');
    $enquireCollection->settitle($developer['title']);
    $enquireCollection->setcontent($developer['content']);
    $enquireCollection->setstatus($developer['status']);
    return $enquireCollection->save();
  }

}
```

> Model/Resource/Developer.php

```
class Epage_Developer_Model_Resource_Developer extends Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Db_Abstract{

  protected function _construct() {
    $this->_init('developer/developer', 'developer_id');
  }

}
```

> Model/Resource/Developer/Collection.php

```
 class Epage_Developer_Model_Resource_Developer_Collection extends Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Db_Collection_Abstract { 
  protected function _construct() {
    //parent::_construct ();
    $this->_init('developer/developer');
  }

}
```

> Block/Adminhtml/Developer/Grid.php

```
<?php 
class Epage_Developer_Block_Adminhtml_Developer_Grid extends Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Grid
{
    public function __construct()
    {  
        parent::__construct();
        $this->setId('developer_Grid');
        $this->setDefaultSort('developer_id');
        $this->setDefaultDir('ASC');
        $this->setSaveParametersInSession(true);

    }/*
    protected function _prepareCollection()
    {
        $collection = Mage::getResourceModel('developer/developer_collection')
                      ->addAttributeToSelect('title')
                      ->addAttributeToSelect('content')
                      ->addAttributeToSelect('status');

             $this->setCollection($collection);
             return parent::_prepareCollection();
    }*/

    protected function _prepareCollection()
    { 
        // Instantiate the collection of data to be display on the grid
        $collection = Mage::getResourceModel('developer/developer_collection')->getCollection()->addAttributeToSelect('*');
        var_dump($collection);
        foreach($collections as $collection) {
            echo $collection->getId();
        }
        $this->setCollection($collection);
        parent::_prepareCollection();
        return $this; 
    }
    protected function _prepareColumns()
    {
        $this->addColumn('developer_id', 
                array(
                        'header' => Mage::helper('developer')->__('ID'),
                        'align' => 'right',
                        'width' => '50px',
                        'index' => 'ID',
                ));
        $this->addColumn('title', 
                array(
                        'header' => Mage::helper('developer')->__('title'),
                        'align' => 'left',
                        'index' => 'title',
                ));
        $this->addColumn('content',
                array(
                        'header' => Mage::helper('developer')->__('content'),
                        'align' => 'left',
                        'index' => 'content',
                ));
        $this->addColumn('status', array(
                        'header'    => Mage::helper('developer')->__('Status'),
                        'width'     => '120',
                        'align'     => 'left',
                        'index'     => 'status',
                        'type'      => 'options',
                        'options'   => array(0 => $this->__('Disabled'), 1 => $this->__('Enabled')),
                        'frame_callback' => array($this, 'decorateStatus')
        ));
        $this->addExportType('*/*/exportCsv', Mage::helper('developer')->__('CSV'));
        $this->addExportType('*/*/exportXml', Mage::helper('developer')->__('XML'));
        return parent::_prepareColumns();
    }
    protected function _prepareMassaction()
    {
        $this->setMassactionIdField('developer_id');
        $this->getMassactionBlock()->setFormFieldName('developer');

        $this->getMassactionBlock()->addItem('delete', array(
                'label'    => Mage::helper('developer')->__('Delete'),
                'url'      => $this->getUrl('*/*/massDelete'),
                'confirm'  => Mage::helper('developer')->__('Are you sure?')
        ));

        $statuses = Mage::getSingleton('developer/developer')->getOptionArray();

        array_unshift($statuses, array('label'=>'', 'value'=>''));
        $this->getMassactionBlock()->addItem('status', array(
                'label'=> Mage::helper('developer')->__('Change status'),
                'url'  => $this->getUrl('*/*/massStatus', array('_current'=>true)),
                'additional' => array(
                        'visibility' => array(
                                'name' => 'status',
                                'type' => 'select',
                                'class' => 'required-entry',
                                'label' => Mage::helper('developer')->__('Status'),
                                'values' => $statuses
                        )
                )
        ));
        return $this;
    }
    protected function _preparePage()
    {
        $this->getCollection()->setPageSize($this->getParam($this->getVarNameLimit(), $this->_defaultLimit));
        $this->getCollection()->setCurPage($this->getParam($this->getVarNamePage(), $this->_defaultPage));
    }
    public function getRowUrl($row)
    {

        return $this->getUrl('*/*/edit', array('id' => $row->getId()));
    }
    public function getGridUrl() {
        return $this->getUrl('*/*/developer_grid', array('developer_id'=> Mage::registry('developer_data')->getId(), '_current' => true));
    }
}
?>
```

which place is error please let know.

My error was this

> Fatal error: Call to undefined method
>   Epage_Developer_Model_Resource_Developer_Collection::getCollection()
>   in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\magentos\app\code\local\Epage\Developer\Block\Adminhtml\Developer\Grid.php
>   on line 27

Answer (score 1):

try this code

```
$collection = Mage::getModel('developer/developer')->getCollection();
```

Answer (score 0):

> Block/Adminhtml/Developer/Grid.php

in your Grid.php Try changing below code

From

```
$collection = Mage::getResourceModel('developer/developer_collection')->getCollection()->addAttributeToSelect('*');
```

To

```
$collection = Mage::getResourceModel('developer/developer_collection')->addAttributeToSelect('*');
```